# Eclipse shows syntax error when using PRId64 from inttypes.h

Tags: 32bit-64bit, eclipse-cdt

When I do

```
#include <inttypes.h>
long long value = 0;
printf("An 8 byte long integer value: %"PRId64".", value);
```

Eclipse shows me a syntax error in the printf line. Anybody knows how to get rid of it? This is the only way I know to have a printf working on both 32-bit and 64-bit architectures and Eclipse errors every few lines make it quite hard to see the real issues.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The question was answered [here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/458015/1018221/#msg_1018221).

You need to add __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS in Project Properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols.